# R, list of duplicates with unique location and date combination

Tags: r, unique

I have a database that holds hold data of animals counted with location and date, for every unique combination of location and date 1 or more animals may have been counted. I want to find the amount of  unique combinations of location and date. After this, I want to find the amount of duplications of only location (so i know how many times each location has been measured in total)

i used `locations <- table(STOWA$locality)` to get a list of each location and the amount of times it occured, but i first need to get a list of every unique combination of location and date and then use `table()` on it.

pseudocode below of what i want to achieve

```
newList <- (where STOWA$locality + STOWA$date = unique)
locations <- table(newList(only on location,not date))
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with simple dplyr code:

```
unique_combination <- df %>% 
    count(animal, location, time)
```

Location:

```
count_location <- df %>%
        count(location)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not this?

```
library(dplyr)

newlist <- df %>% group_by(locality, date) %>% slice_head()
```

this will give you one unique combination for each, basically the first row.